# What specific Spark libraries are 'Provided'?

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark

In the official Spark [documentation](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/cluster-overview.html) it is explained that the term *application jar* corresponds to:

> A jar containing the user's Spark application. In some cases users will want to create an "uber jar" containing their application along with its dependencies. The user's jar should never include Hadoop or Spark libraries, however, these will be added at runtime

This can be easily taken care of by using 'Provided' scope in maven or sbt:

```
"org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % sparkVersion % Provided
```

However, I might be missing something obvious here, but I could not find a straight answer, what are the specific libraries that will be added at runtime? Will it be just the core ones (e.g. spark-core, hadoop-core) or will some others (example: spark-streaming, hadoop-hdfs) be added as well?

Is there a way to check this and get the actual list of Spark dependencies that will be added at runtime and hence can be marked as Provided?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: all Spark libraries and the hadoop version you chose when you downloaded Spark from the [download page](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html).

The longer answer is: it depends on the **deployment mode** you're using:

1. **Local Mode**: since there's only one JVM in local mode, and that's the Driver application's JVM - then it depends on how you packaged your driver app. If you didn't (e.g. running directly from IDE), then defining a dependency as "provided" doesn't mean anything, so  whichever libraries you have in your SBT file will be present in runtime. If you package your driver application and try to run it with Spark marked as provided, you'll probably see failures unless you bring these jars into the mix some other way (but local mode isn't really meant for that anyway...).
2. **Standalone Mode**: if you deployed one of the pre-built packages available at the download page onto your cluster (master and worker machines), they contain all of Spark's libraries (including Spark SQL, Streaming, GraphX...) and the Hadoop version you chose. If you deployed jars that you built yourself - well, then it depends on what and how you packaged...
3. **Yarn Mode**: when you submit a Spark application to a YARN manager, you set the Spark jar location for the application to use (via parameter `spark.yarn.jar`) - whatever that jar (or jars) contain will be loaded. Once again - if that jar is one of the pre-built ones, it contains all Spark libraries and the chosen Hadoop version

Comment: This answer is clear and to the point. In my case it's especially useful that the three modes are explained. Btw, things are further complicated when we are in vendor specific world, and the jar is not necessarily standard, but even in that case this answer provides the necessary hints to get to the right piece of information